# Can VBA code for AutoCad be run on back end server for a web application?

Tags: vba, web-applications, backend, autocad

I am new to back end server development. I have questions if VBA code for AutoCad can be run on the back end server.

For an example, the GUI is designed on the website. Inputs are sent to the back end server which will use VBA code to draw on AutoCad. The final drawing will be saved on back end server and sent to the website as output.

Is this possible? Any limitation or things that I should note?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

VBA is designed to operate in the client, regardless of whether it is AutoCAD, Excel, or Word.

AutoCAD does have other extensibility options, but VBA is not something that you'll be able to run as a back-end.

Comment: Is there other options for running autocad on the backend?